# How to understand the sentence "Such a binding is defined once and never changed."?

Tags: javascript, function

I am currently reading *Eluoquent Javascript*. [In chapter 3](https://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html#h_y6WGSsYfER) there are sentences that i do not understand. I bolded those sentences:

> A function binding usually simply acts as a name for a specific piece
> of the program. **Such a binding is defined once and never changed**.
> This makes it easy to confuse the function and its name.
>
> But the two are different. A function value can do all the things that
> other values can do—you can use it in arbitrary expressions, not just
> call it. It is possible to store a function value in a new binding,
> pass it as an argument to a function, and so on. **Similarly, a
> binding that holds a function is still just a regular binding and can,
> if not constant, be assigned a new value, like so**:
>
> ```
> let launchMissiles = function() {
>   missileSystem.launch("now");
> };
> if (safeMode) {
>   launchMissiles = function() {/* do nothing */};
> }
> ```

The first bolded sentence states that a function binding is defined once and never changed, but the second one states that the binding that holds a function can be assigned a new value, in other words, changed. I don't get it, can anyone explain?

Comment: I think what the first sentence is trying to say is that in a regular js program you'd write `function test() { }` and would never reassign `test` (although you could).

Comment: The "usually" from the previous sentence carries over, it's just not repeated anymore. "Such a binding is [usually] defined once and [usually] never changed." It doesn't say that you *can't* change it.

Comment: @GuyIncognito Can you make that an answer please? You might also include that up that section, [all "function bindings" were created with `const`](https://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html#p_pBsAbh0THD). It really needs to distinguish between `let` bindings, `var` bindings, and `const` bindings.